# Change the Data in a http post request with input text box

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

The code I have so far is for getting data from a web service, which accepts a sql query and returns JSON data. When I hard code myID to a ID in the DB, I get data. I am trying to make this changeable on runtime, so I am trying to use an input text box bound to myID. This is throwing an error unexpected token , when I type in the same ID into the myID. Any thoughts how I can bind the text in the text box to the command in my $http object? Thanks!!!

```
    myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {

                  var responsePromise = $http({
                      url: "http://mywebservice/sql",
                      method: "POST",
                      data: {
                          Command: ["select * from mytable where id = " + {{myID}}]
                      },
                      withCredentials: true,
                      headers: {
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                          'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                      }
                  }).
                  success(function (resp, status, headers, config) {
                      $scope.message = resp.Data;
                      $scope.status = status;
                      $scope.success = resp.Success;
                      $scope.respLogs = resp.Logs[0].Message;
                  }).
                  error(function (resp, status, headers, config) {

                  });
```

myApp DIV

```
<input  type="text" ng-model="myID" />
```

**Update 1:**

Tried that, still no joy. When i change the text in the text box to an ID in the  DB, I see no response with the below error in my Javascript console.

In other words:

```
Command: ["select * from [es.device_platf.bug] where id = " + $scope.hsdid]
```

doesnt work, but

`Command: ["select * from [es.device_platf.bug] where id = '1234567'"]` 
works

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
    at Object.parse (native)
    at wc (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:15:401)
    at $b (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:82:143)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:83:50
    at m (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at fd (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:83:32)
    at c (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:84:211)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:120:182
    at n.$get.n.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:134:493)
    at n.$get.n.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:132:9)
```

Comment: Seriously you need to add fiddle if you need any more help than this now bro!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `{{myId}}` to `$scope.myID`

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {

         var responsePromise = $http({
             url: "http://mywebservice/sql",
             method: "POST",
             data: {
                 Command: ["select * from mytable where id = " + $scope.myID] // changes here
             },
             withCredentials: true,
             headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
             }
         }).
         success(function(resp, status, headers, config) {
             $scope.message = resp.Data;
             $scope.status = status;
             $scope.success = resp.Success;
             $scope.respLogs = resp.Logs[0].Message;
         }).
         error(function(resp, status, headers, config) {

         });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using syntax `{{}}` in your JavaScript file but that syntax is used in HTML.
2. When you use `ng-model="myID"` you have in your controller a `var` accessible as `$scope.myID`.

So change:

```
Command: ["select * from mytable where id = " + {{myID}}]
```

to:

```
Command: ["select * from mytable where id = " + $scope.myID]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. I haven't found doc about 'Command'. My advice: Compose the query in your model. In  your controller you can invoke the service such that: 
$http({
url:"..", 
method:'POST', 
data: {param1: param1Value, param2: param2Value...}
).sucess...